# How to rasterize sf geometries tile by tile?

Tags: r, loops, spatial, r-sf, rasterize

What I´m looking for is a way to rasterize (or fasterize) geometries within each tile of a certain extent step by step and join the parts of the rasterized geometries to entire raster objects.

```
## create sample data

# create a frame
library(sf)
ob = st_sf(st_sfc(st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0,0), c(0,9), c(6,9), c(6,0), c(0,0)))))
# create tiles
library(GSIF)
tl <- getSpatialTiles(as(ob, 'Spatial'), block.x=3, overlap.percent=2)
plot(tl)
# create sample polygons
g <- st_sfc(st_point(c(1,2)), st_point(c(5,6)), st_point(c(2,4)), st_point(c(3,3)), st_point(c(3,4)), st_point(c(4,5)))
g.b <- st_buffer(g,0.6)
p <- st_sf(value = ceiling(10*runif(6)),
           geometry = st_sfc(g.b))
plot(p, add=TRUE)
```

Cropping the polygons (or parts of polygons) that are within each tile works fine , i guess. My actual goal is to process the data tile by tile. It looks like the following loop does this and also joins the parts of the polygons to entire polygons. Well, the output (cr) is the same as the input (p)... I thought that this step might be necessary in order to rasterize the resulting (parts of) polygons in the next step. i didn´t expect that the polygons would be joined. I was trying to build a loop based on the intermediate result, therefore following lines are add:

```
# crop polygons (or parts) for each tile
result <- p
for(i in 1:length(tl)) {cr <- rbind(result, st_crop(p, tl[i]))}
cr <- cr[-7,]
library(scales)
plot(st_geometry(cr), col=alpha("white", 0.5), add=TRUE)
```

However, I struggle rasterizing the (intermediate) results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myF <- function(i){return(st_crop(p, tl[i]))}
cr <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(tl), myF))
```